# C++ tag synonyms

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

Apparently, there are two duplicate(?) tags: [c++11](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) and [c++0x](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b0x). The only difference between the two is that [c++0x](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b0x) was the WIP name before [c++11](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) was finalized (at the last few meetings).

For someone thinking this will be of more relevance on [Stack Overflow][1], the tag "c++0x" is already set as a duplicate of "c++11". That is all I'm asking here. For a tag synonym.

[1]: Apparently, there are two duplicate(?) tags: [c++11](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) and [c++0x](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b0x). The only difference between the two is that [c++0x](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b0x) was the WIP name before [c++11](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) was finalized (at the last few meetings).

Comment: Something to consider: Given the nature of Programmers, do we need to distinguish between versions of languages? Some concepts do require it (for example, a question earlier about modeling the C++ concept of "friend" in UML). But even so, I don't think version-specific tags might be required. This might have been discussed, but before merging, it might be something to decide: Do we need c++0x or c++11 or can we merge them all into c++?

Comment: [Here is the previous discussion.](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3663/should-there-be-tags-for-language-and-framework-versions) I don't entirely agree with the community, but there isn't overwhelming discussion in favor of or against version-specific tags. In the mean time, I don't have a problem merging c++0x into c++11 if no objections come out of this question.

Comment: @ThomasOwens it helps to say, "I have to use C++03 (as per old school compiler reqs or workplace policy) so please don't give me any answers that need C++11 features."

Comment: My only concern is that once you get into such details, wouldn't Stack Overflow be better? Once you move from design to implementation (and therefore language-specific things), you've moved from the whiteboard or the conference room to the IDE.

Comment: @ThomasOwens for example, tagged [tag:c89] and the question is how to "determine integer types size at compile time". With c89, you don't have <stdint.h>, so the tag gives a bit of a clue. This could be caused by project requirements saying that "use of <stdint.h> is disallowed"

Comment: I would migrate that question to Stack Overflow. I don't see how that question can be on-topic for us. I presume that there may be design questions, but I'm not sure if separate version tags are appropriate.

Comment: @ThomasOwens I guess this question also applies to StackOverflow, but it does apply here also. Those are duplicates as C++0x and C++11 refer to the same standard

Comment: I agree with @ThomasOwens, I see no use in specifying a version of C++ required, because I can't think of a question where version is relevant and the question is still on topic. version tags would just add clutter more often than useful information.