# Why no C-- tags?

Tags: support, tags

I've noticed that there are various tags for C++, such as:

- [c++](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)
- [c++03](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b03)
- [c++0x & c++11](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5289/c-duplicate-tags)

But there are tags for "c--". Can we add some? I don't have enough reputation to create tags.

---

Links on C--:

- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C--)
- [Official Website](http://www.cminusminus.org/) ([Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20080822062234/http://www.cminusminus.org/))

Comment: Do you have a question to ask about C--? If so go ahead and ask it and I'll gladly add the C-- tag to your question. If not however, then there was clearly no need for the C-- tag in the past and still none for it right now. Find a question about C-- in the past on programmers and I'll add the tag there if you wish..

Comment: @deadman http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/177373/where-does-the-mm-come-from-in-gtkmm-glibmm-etc

Comment: I failed, doesn't look like I'm allowed to do that in edit. Perhaps someone else can.

Comment: semi related from MSO http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148718

Comment: your question has 5 tags already that is the maximum amount of tags a question can have.

Comment: @Ryathal I never added the c tag? Jimmy Hoffa tried adding c-- it says. But I guess it changed it to c. Maybe c-minus-minus?

Comment: @ColeJohnson that makes sense, 'c--' isn't allowed as a tag it becomes c, i removed it and added [tag:c-minus-minus]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, C-- is not a language meant to be written by programmers directly, but rather an intermediary language that high-level-language compilers generate. Therefore, I doubt that anyone who is not working on compilers would ever have to ask a question about C--; that makes C-- a very narrow topic, possibly too narrow for this site.

Comment: This is what I was looking for.

Comment: Now why do you not have a name?

Comment: Cole Johnson: I had a name, but changed it to this pseudo-anonymous name to protest against something in the past

Answer (score 5):

Tags don't exist without a question (or several) for them to be attached to.

If there is a question about "c--" then feel free to add the tag.

Comment: I can't make tags :/